# Read command line arguments with input redirection operator in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I need to read command line arguments. First arg is script name. second one is redirection operator i.e. "<" and third one is input filename. When I tried to use "$#", I got 0. When I used "$*", it gave me nothing. I have to use "<" this operator. My input file consists of all user input data. If I don't use the operator, It asks user for the input. Can someone please help me? Thank you !

Command Line :

```
./script_name < input_file
```

Script:

```
 echo "$*"       # gave nothing
 echo "$#"       # gave me 0
```

I need to read input filename and store it to some variable. Then I have to change the extension of it. Any help/suggestions should be appreciated.

Comment: `./script_name input_file`, then `echo $1`.

Comment: I have to read all lines from my input file. It has all the user input. If I don't use that operator, It will prompt the user for input.

Comment: Show your script, or an equivalent example, so we can see exactly how it reads from standard input

Comment: I am using "for i in $(cat input_file); do ----My code and some read statements---; done"

Comment: @Rock26, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: ...and see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for the best-practices / correct way to read from a file line-by-line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user runs:

```
./script_name <input_file
```

...that's **exactly** equivalent to if they did the following:

```
(exec <input_file; exec ./script_name)
```

...first redirecting stdin from `input_file`, then invoking the script named `./script_name` *without any arguments*.

There are operating-system-specific interfaces you can use to get the filename associated with a handle (when it has one), but to use one of these would make your script only able to run on an operating system providing that interface; it's not worth it.

```
# very, very linux-specific, won't work for "cat foo | ./yourscript", generally evil
if filename=$(readlink /proc/self/fd/0) && [[ -e $filename ]]; then
  set -- "$@" "$filename" # append filename to the end of the argument list
fi
```

---

If you want to avoid prompting for input when an argument is given, *and to have the filename of that argument*, then don't take it on stdin but as an argument, and do the redirection yourself **within the script**:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 ]]; then
  exec <"$1" # this redirects your stdin to come from the file
fi

# ...put other logic here...
```

...and have users invoke your script as:

```
./script_name input_file
```

---

Just as `./yourscript <filename` runs `yourscript` with the contents of `filename` on its standard input, a script invoked with `./yourscript filename` which invokes `exec <"$1"` will have the contents of `filename` on its stdin after executing that command.

Comment: Thanks @charles. It works perfectly fine. I appreciate your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

`<` is used for input redirection. And whatever is at the right side of `<` is NOT a command line argument.

So, when you do `./script_name < input_file` , there will be zero (0) command line arguments passed to the script, hence `$#` will be zero.

For your puprpose you need to call your script as:

```
./script_name input_file
```

And in your script you can change the extension with something like:

```
mv -- "$1" "${1}_new_extension"
```

**Edit**: This was not what OP wanted to do.

---

Altough, there is already another spot on answer, I will write this for the sake of completeness. If you *have* to use the '<' redirection you can do something like this in your script.

```
while read filename; do
mv -- "$filename" "${filename}_bak"
done
```

And call the script as, `./script < input_file`. However, note that you will not be able to take inputs from `stdin` in this case.

Comment: Needs more quotes (ie. `mv -- "$1" "${1}_new_extension"`). The `--` is necessary to support filenames that start with dashes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy good points. I have edited. Although it seems that OP is trying to do something else, as is seen in the comments in question now..

Comment: Thanks @sps. I can not remove "<" operator. If I do that, script will prompt user for inputs. I don't want user to provide input as it is already there in that input_file.

Comment: @Rock26, to the contrary, you can in fact remove the `<` -- see my answer, showing how to do the same thing the `<` would do *from within the script*.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you're hoping to take redirection operators as arguments to your script, you're not going to be able to do that without surrounding your command line arguments in quotes:

`./script_name "<input_file"`

The reason for this is that the shell (at least bash or zsh) processes the command before ever invoking your script. When the shell interprets your command, it reads:

```
[shell command (./script_name)][shell input redirection (<input_file)]
```

invoking your script with quotes effectively results in:

```
[shell command (./script_name)][script argument ("<input_file")]
```

Sorry this is a few years late; hopefully someone will find this useful.